# Is Ubuntu 14.04 slower on low-end graphics cards than 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I started upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 (from 12.04) when it said that if I installed it, it might make me have a "slow environment" because of my graphics card. I cancelled the upgrade because of my computer, that could be a very distinct possibility. I am using an Acer C720 Chromebook dual booted with Ubuntu 12.04 unity. I have very little programming and Ubuntu experience, I have only been using it for 2 months.

Should I Upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you must.

Open a terminal and copy paste the following:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Using the latest features is always more secure, reliable and you will allways be up to date.

Do a system clean with bleachbit after the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

and then

```
sudo bleachbit
```

and perform the clean up.

Comment: "*Yes, you must.*" Why? Ubuntu 12.04 [remains supported until April 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: Because he will have newer features, he has hardware that supports that version and he will get even more support, Ubuntu 14.04 is now in version 14.04.1 so it is quite stable now to recommend people to update, if you want to keep 12.04 you can but the newer the better allways ;) if people take time to code new things and add new functions is to that people can take advantage of it.

Comment: But *SnorriChinchilla* described about the doubts in the speed with the low-end graphics card